# golang gcc c++ existing static library can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, go, gcc, linker

I tried to link an existing C++ library to go code. The C++ library only has a static library and a header file, no source code.

I used swigc to generate a libfoo.go and I wrote a simple libb.go to build this library. This worked well on ubuntu 16.04 with gcc-6 earlier.

However, once I upgraded to ubuntu 18, and even with older go1.9 and gcc-6, which used to work, I am hitting the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libfoo.a(parser.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `xmlSAX2IgnorableWhitespace' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/libfoo.a(tree.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I have downgraded both go compiler and gcc to the version that used to work.

The following is the libb.go that used to work

```
/*
#cgo CXXFLAGS: -std=c++11 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 -w
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/include -w
#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl -rpath,./lib, -L${SRCDIR}/lib -l:libfoo.a  -l:libxml2.a 
*/
import "C"
```

What should I do get this fixed? I searched and it seems that I have to recompile that static library, which is mission impossible in my case. I tried to pass the -no-pie parameter to LDFLAGS, that didn't work either.

Comment: "What should I do get this fixed?" - Why don't you try what the error message so helpfully told you "recompile with -fPIC" ?

Comment: I did a bit of research and found [this](https://bugs.debian.org/823014) (since Ubuntu pulls most of the packages from Debian testing, it is very likely to be relevant). Basically this means on your new OS release you may have Go stdlib built in PIE mode and so it naturally cannot link with the code of the non-compatible link mode. All-in-all, I think this question is unfit for SO as it apparently requires lots of backs-and-forth to get to the root of the problem. Hence could you please post a message [to the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts/) instead?

Comment: Please be sure to also include the following: 1) "what Go" are you using for bulding—whether it's the Go compiler provided by GCC of the reference Go implementation (that is, you've installed the `golang-go` package). 2) include the output of `go version` and `go env`. 3) Version of your OS and GCC.

Comment: @kostix thank you for advice! I have already posted this question to the group alias. btw: I don't have the c++ source code so I am not able to recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

I also run into this problem these days. Finally, I found that adding below lines

```
"env CGO_LDFLAGS=-no-pie"
```

to go build command line could solve this problem. For example,

```
"env CGO_LDFLAGS=-no-pie go build -o main main.go"
```